# Principal part of Laurent series of $\frac{1}{2-e^z}$ at $z=\ln 2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

How can I determine the principal part of the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{2-e^z}$ at $z=\ln 2$ and  the principal part of the Laurent series of $\frac{e^{-z}}{1-z}$ at $z=1$?

I know the solutions are $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{e^{-1}}{1-z}$, respectively. I was wondering if there are are any tricks/formulas to do this or if I have to look at the series representations of the given functions.

For the 2nd problem I saw the solution $\lim_{z \to \ln 2}(z-\ln 2)\frac{1}{z-e^{z}}=-\frac{1}{2}$. What did the author do here? I don't understand why we are evaluating this limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first started out, here are some things which helped me. Whenever I'm given some function, and I'm asked to find the Laruent Expansion (eg the first few terms or whatever) about some point $a$, I would always change variables and define say $t=z-a$, so that $z=a+t$, and then I have to expand in powers of $t$. From then, it is a matter of using the common series expansions (eg for $\sin t,\cos t,e^t$ and particularly important is $\frac{1}{1-t}$ and also $(1+t)^{\alpha}$ when using the principal branch). Knowing these series with your eyes closed (along with the knowledge of how to manipulate series) will help you so much.

Here's an example calculation. As in your example, consider the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{2-e^z}$; we wish to calculate the principal part of the Laurent expansion about $\ln 2$. This means, we write $z=\ln 2 + t$, and then we want to expand it in powers of $t$. In other words, we want to write something like
\begin{align}
f(\ln 2+t)=\underbrace{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nt^n}_{\text{principal part}} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n
\end{align}
and our task is to figure out what the coefficients $a_n$ are when $n\leq -1$. So, let's calculate:
\begin{align}
f((\ln 2) + t)&=\frac{1}{2-e^{(\ln 2) +t}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2-e^{\ln 2}e^t}\\
&=\frac{1}{2-2e^t}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-e^t}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^3)\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{-t-\frac{t^2}{2}-O(t^3)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2t}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{t}{2}+O(t^2))}\tag{$*$}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2t}\cdot\left[1-\left(\frac{t}{2}+O(t^2)\right)+ O\left(\frac{t}{2}+O(t^2)\right)\right]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2t}\cdot\left[1-\frac{t}{2}+O(t^2)\right]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2t}+\frac{1}{4}+O(t)
\end{align}
So, the principal part of the Laurent expansion (i.e the part with the "negative powers")
is $-\frac{1}{2t}$. Note that if we hadn't made this translation, the intermediate steps wouldn't change drastically, it's just more writing; we can write the above equivalently as
\begin{align}
f(z)&=-\frac{1}{2(z-\ln 2)}+\frac{1}{4}+O(z-\ln 2)
\end{align}
So, this is where the $-\frac{1}{2}$ is coming from.

Let's recap what we did: first I made the substitution $z=\ln 2 +t$ essentially to simplify the writing and "remove clutter". Next, we just massaged the terms as much as possible. Then, the crucial step is in plugging in the series definition into the step $\frac{1}{1-e^t}$, then factoring out the $t$ from the denominator. Then, we're left with something like $\frac{1}{1-\zeta}$; in the above calculation I had $\zeta=t+O(t)$, and if $t$ is small enough then we will have $\zeta$ small as well (partcularly $|\zeta|<1$) and hence we can expand into the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-\zeta}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\zeta^n$.

As you can see, from my calculation, I also figured out that the constant term of the Laurent expansion is $\frac{1}{4}$; this is because I used a second order expansion $e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^3)$. If I kept a higher power $e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}+O(t^4)$, then I would also be able to figure out the linear term of the Laurent expansion and so on.

Now, as for why the author calculated the limit $\lim\limits_{z\to \ln 2}\frac{(z-\ln 2)}{2-e^z}$, it is because the author has the insight that $2-e^z$ has a zero of order 1 at $\ln 2$; meaning $2-e^z = (z-\ln 2)g(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g$ such that $g(\ln 2)\neq 0$ (this corresponds to my step $(*)$ above where I factored the $t$ from the denominator). Therefore, $\frac{1}{2-e^z}=\frac{1}{z-\ln 2}\frac{1}{g(z)}$, so to figure out the principal part, we simply need to know what is $g(\ln 2)$; then we will have $\frac{1}{2-e^z}=\frac{1}{g(\ln 2)(z-\ln 2)}+ \text{higher powers}$, thus the principal part will be determined once we calculate the value of $\frac{1}{g(\ln 2)}=\lim\limits_{z\to \ln 2}\frac{z-\ln 2}{2-e^z}$.

Personally, I do not like this approach when first starting out because it takes some time to recognize things like "oh this function has a zero of order ... at ..., therefore the reciprocal has a pole of order ... at ..." and things like that. When one has no clue how to begin (like me when I first learnt this stuff), I much rather go through the above more systematic procedure (which with some practice, I think is much quicker than calculating the limits, especially for more complicated functions, which may require several rounds of L'Hopital's rule).

Answer (score -1):

$f(z)=\frac1{2-e^z}$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z=\ln2$, so the Laurent series is of the form $$f(z)=\frac{a_{-1}}{z-\ln2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-\ln2)^n$$  Now it should be clear that $a_{-1}=\lim_{z\to\ln2}(z-\ln2)f(z)$